# exclude directory in hg commands by default

Tags: mercurial

I'm working in a project 
I used to do things like:

```
hg grep TODO
```

to find stuff that needs fixing for example.
But now I have included source code from other projects and 
hg grep TODO becomes useless because of the existence of TODO's in the added source code projects which is not mine. Now I can add an parameter --exclude=frameworks to the command but
typing that each time is annoying...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [alias](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias) section of hgrc is suited for this. You could add this to your local `.hgrc` or if this is relevant for just this repository, to your `.hg/hgrc`:

```
[alias]
xgrep = grep --exclude=frameworks
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is adding an alias in your shell's configuration file (for example `~/.bashrc`) or profile (`~/.profile`):

```
alias hg-grep="hg grep --exclude=frameworks"
```

type `. ~/.bashrc` or just start a new shell to have the setting in effect. You'll get the behavior you want with `hg-grep TODO`, but can still use the original with `hg grep TODO`.